# Parsing an XML file (with embedded dictionaries) into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working on a project where I need to parse a large XML file (6gbs) and then run some transformation on the data. Initially I had some issues with the file size, but I have managed to build a loop that dumps my memory after running, so now I am really keen to get the data into a pandas dataframe as I think it would be ideal for what I need to do. Here's the simple loop as it stands:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(XML_FILE):
    if elem.tag == "record":
        if (elem.attrib.get("category") != 'X') & (elem.attrib.get("category") != 'Y'):
            if (elem.attrib.get("sub-category") == 'Z'):
                for node in elem.getiterator():
                    print(node.attrib)
                break
        elem.clear()
```

Using the above I can iterate through the XML file, as each record I want is between a record tag. Essentially I need to go through the branches inside that record tag, and parse them into a pandas dataframe with the node.tag as the columns and the node.attrib as the values.

I am, however, having issues transposing the tags into columns headers, and parsing the node.attrib as they are stored as dictionary values. Is it possible for me to parse through this XML file, going from record to record and parsing the branches into a dataframe, possibly storing the dictionary values as indeces or something in the pandas dataframe?

Comment: Create a detailed dictionary after parsing the node-.attrib values and then import that to pandas dataframe.

Comment: @min2bro not sure what you mean be a detailed dictionary, can't find any information online about those? I'm struggling to zip things into a dictionary because the node.attrib values are a dictionary in of itself, so if I try to zip the keys/values pairings it won't work

Comment: Can you share the sample xml to work on?